# LO Writer: Two tables have no empty line between them, yet appear on two separated pages

Tags: libreoffice

In an RTF document opened with LO writer I have two tables:

```
Table 1
Table 2
```

One the one hand, the tables are juxtaposed one to another (there is no empty space between them).

On the other hand, the tables are on separated pages (I have no idea why - has to do with pasting).

### My tables:

[image]

---

### My question:

How to move my two tables into the same page?

Comment: Are page feeds between tables an **RTF** document problem only or does it apply to Word and ODT files too?

Comment: From my check the exact same problem happens with ODT as well. I don't know about MS Word extensions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First I should ask to kindly NOT upvoting this very answer**.

Sadly, none of the two answers above helped, so I just copied each table into a new RTF document and gladly I had no formatting problems.

Again, not a solution, but still helped.

Answer (score 0):

Merge Table: combines two consecutive tables into a single table. The tables must be directly next to each other and not separated by an empty paragraph.

Choose Table - Merge Table

I have found some help here: https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Merge_Table

Comment: Try to check 'Formatting marks' in 'View', that may reveal something.

Comment: Please see the edit in my question. I don't think merging rows is what I need here.

Comment: What I had in thought with 'Formatting marks' in 'View' is that if you could see the Page Break line (there certainly is one), you could just click on it and remove it.

Comment: Dominik, sadly I don't have any formatting remark whatsoever between the two tables so nothing to remove.

Comment: Also, I don't know how to add one under my first table.

Answer (score 0):

Without having your actual document to work with I came up with this link:

- [Can't remove unwanted page break before table](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/110308/cant-remove-unwanted-page-break-before-table/)

There are two answers posted on the link summarized below:

#### Answer 1:

- Right-click in the table, and choose Table.
- Click the Text Flow tab.
- Clear the Break check box.

#### Answer 2:

- This answer has graphics so visit the link above to see it. It looks like it might not be helpful but you should verify.

Comment: Hi ! This checkbox was actually already cleared...